# Logback doesn't log into file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm using logback in my project and it doesn't log into a file.

My logback.xml looks like this

```
<property file="api.properties"/>

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>c:/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>c:/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="JDBC" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>
<logger name="RESTSecurity" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>
<logger name="models" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<!-- Strictly speaking, the level attribute is not necessary since -->
<!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default.       -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

and it's placed in WEB-INF/classes.

I use these dependencies

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run my app on WebLogic server I get my log messages in the console but it doesn't create log files.
Anyone know what could be wrong?

EDIT:
I tried using both

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("JDBC");
```

and

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Roles.class);
```

as that class is in JDBC package.
Then I just do

```
 logger.info("Initializing roles");
```

EDIT2: 
Because log messages i get in console looks different from what is in logback.xml it looks like it does ignore my logback.xml at all.

Comment: Please show your code as you are using different loggers in logback configuration.

Comment: @Rouliboy i've added it in EDIT

Comment: Try removing newline and spaces between `<fileNamePattern>c:/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log` and `</fileNamePattern>`. Are you sure the application has the permission to create corresponding file and `c:/archived` directory already exists?

Comment: Tried, and seems like it's not the issue. c:/archived exists and in i guess it should, i've added write rights to processes running under users.

Comment: Are the log in console following the pattern you defined ? Do their format change when you change the pattern in the logback.xml ?

Comment: VI 12, 2017 9:28:26 AM. JDBC.Roles getRoles
INFO: Initializing roles
Actually it looks like it's not at all.
EDIT: It looks like application is ignoring my logback.xml at all. But it's in correct folder on classpath.

Comment: Where is located your logback.xml? How is packaged your application? WAR? EAR?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and also stepping through the init phase of logback? There is a chance that you might see which configuration logback picks during debugging.

Comment: @Rouliboy it is packaged as WAR and logback.xml is in WEB-INF/classes in that WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must come from Weblogic which does not pick up SLF4J/Logback from your classpath.

Add the following `prefer-application-packages` to your `weblogic.xml` :

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
    <package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the appenders to the log level, if you want DEBUG to log to file, add the ref like this:

```
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. But as mentioned in comments above it looks like my application is ignoring logback.xml at all so maybe it's not fault in xml file. I've updated post to mention it.